How to use .env with SpringBoot
i'am learning Springboot , i want use .env for save my data postgreSQL . I create .env file on my root project same level to my pom.xml and i use my variable to my application.properties lika that :
.env : 
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=****************
SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=*********
SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=******************

And I have that on my application.properties :
spring.application.name=chatop_FS

dotenv.path=.env

spring.datasource.url=:${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}


logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
#Tomcat configuration
server.port=5656

Spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher

But Whan i run my app , it's not working . . .  Can you help me please ?

I don't get it. Why would you need to have a separate .env file? You can directly put the database information inside properties file.

@BlackList96 Well for security ! It's better methode to add informations database on .env file for security app . Have you idea for that is not working ?

The Spring .properties files are config files and thus basically the same as dotenv files. You usually have different properties files for different purposes, eg a base one, one for development (which you also add to VCS), one specifically for production (which you wouldn't add to VCS since here sits some sensitive data), ... You'll get the idea.

@Slevin Well if i understand what you mean , i do create another properties for my project to use .env file ?

You should use a .properties (or yaml) file instead of your .env file. In Spring properties files are automatically assiciated with a corresponding profile, so you can turn on and off these profiles as required and also turn on and off beans on specific profiles. The Spring documentation willl give you more information of how to use these properties files.

@Slevin I understand there is another way but, I have seen a lot of topics where it is possible to use an .env file and be able to keep your data in it. Does this mean that today this method no longer works, that of .env?

dotenv files don't play a decent role in Spring applications, since usually you ship the application combined with the server (eg Tomcat) in once. So there is no need for them, while for Webapplications coded in JS or Python or something else, which for example you deploy using a service like Heroku, you somehow have to externalize sensitive data. It's not that the concept of .env is outdated, it's just that Spring doesn't require it. Spring is Java based und uses some kind of pimped Java properties files.

To be clear, .env is just a file holding data. That's all. It's not a method or some magic or somewhat else. You could store your grandma's recipes or even a base64 encoded image of your girlfriend. By convention it's a file used to store key value pairs of config data, and there are services which accept these kind of files to process this data. Spring doesn't need them, Spring uses Java .properties (or YAML) for that.

To hide the database information in the application.properties file you must:
creates a “database.properties” file in this location: src/main/ressources
Then enter this connection information in the “database.properties” file:
spring.datasource.url=YOURURLBDD
spring.datasource.username=YOURUSER
spring.datasource.password=YOURPASSWORD


Then go to my file application.properties and add the import line from my file “database.properties”
spring.config.import=classpath:database.properties

Then launch my application, everything works.

Well it doesn't makes any difference as such. You are just referring one file to another. Be it single application.properties or two separate files, you need to ship all of that to the production and properties files will be part of your .jar file that is actually going to run. So, technically  .env makes sense for JS environment but not for Java environment.
